# Loading Java Builder Object from Yaml file

Tags: java, yaml, builder-pattern

I have created a Bean Class using Builder Pattern and having issues creating an object from a yaml file.

Here is a sample class (Actual class is quite big, this is just an excerpt incase if you wanted to answer with an example):

```
public class ClientBuilder {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String displayName;

    private ClientBuilder(Builder builder) { 
        firstName   = builder.firstName; 
        lastName    = builder.lastName; 
        displayName = builder.displayName;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private final String displayName; // Mandatory Attribute

        public Builder( String displayName ) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Builder setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public ClientBuilder build() {
            return new ClientBuilder(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
        sbf.append("New Company Object: \n");
        sbf.append("firstName   : " +  this.firstName   + "\n");
        sbf.append("lastName    : " +  this.lastName    + "\n");
        sbf.append("displayName : " +  this.displayName + "\n");
        return sbf.toString();
    }
}
```

I am using snakeyaml to load the file but any yaml api would work. Since the `displayName` is a mandatory param, I want to pass that value while creating the instance. The other params can be passed while creating the object but I would like the option to load them through yaml file.

I am able to load the yaml file if I use java bean. Is there a way to instantiate builder objects?

I tried:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/client.yaml"));
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Builder builder = new Builder("Display Name");
builder = (Builder) yaml.loadAs(input, ClientBuilder.Builder.class);
ClientBuilder client = builder.build();
System.out.println(client.toString());
```

but I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ClientBuilder$Builder; exception=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ClientBuilder$Builder.<init>()
 in 'reader', line 2, column 1:
    firstName: "Jaypal"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SnakeYaml is a very powerful library & it provides support for creating instance based on constructor injection.

```
/**
 * create JavaBean
 */
public void testGetBeanAssumeClass() {
    String data = "--- !!org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Person\nfirstName: Andrey\nage: 99";
    Object obj = construct(data);
    assertNotNull(obj);
    assertTrue("Unexpected: " + obj.getClass().toString(), obj instanceof Person);
    Person person = (Person) obj;
    assertEquals("Andrey", person.getFirstName());
    assertNull(person.getLastName());
    assertEquals(99, person.getAge().intValue());
}

/**
 * create instance using constructor arguments
 */
public void testGetConstructorBean() {
    String data = "--- !!org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Person [ Andrey, Somov, 99 ]";
    Object obj = construct(data);
    assertNotNull(obj);
    assertTrue(obj.getClass().toString(), obj instanceof Person);
    Person person = (Person) obj;
    assertEquals("Andrey", person.getFirstName());
    assertEquals("Somov", person.getLastName());
    assertEquals(99, person.getAge().intValue());
}
```

[Junit code sample](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/ConstructorTest.java) can be viewed here.
So your code still holds good. You may need to change yaml content with proper format. Once done, you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is about there not being a no-arg constructor in `Builder`, as you probably figured out.

What you could do is to allow no-arg constructor for `Builder` and add corresponding setter and getter for `displayName` to it. Then simply throw an exception in `build()` if `displayName` is not set (or provide a default value for it). The exception can be a runtime one, or you could make it clear and add an explicit `throws`.

While it is not the prettiest solution, it should work just fine. The fact that the `Builder` is created without a mandatory argument should not matter, as it is the `ClientBuilder` that needs to be constructed properly (as the factory/builder is used to ensure that each instance of whatever it is building is correct).

I have no way to access any yaml parsing tools for Java currently, but if there is any way I could improve my answer, let me know - I will be happy to do so.

Comment: Thanks Sorrow for leaving an answer. Yes, adding a no arg constructor works but it _only_ works if I make all the `setters` of my `Builder` class as `void` instead of `Builder` return type. If I loose the ability of having the fluent interface then I guess I should just go with bean pattern. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You probably should not stick too much with the patterns, they should be more _guidelines rather than strict code_ ;) There is nothing preventing you from keeping the setters the way they are, at least I am not seeing it. Yes, there is a risk that `Builder` is in incorrect state (no `displayName` set), but it is there even if your setters return `void`. The trick here is delaying the moment when the incorrect state really matters. Does it matter when constructing `Builder`, or rather `ClientBuilder`? The latter seems more appropriate in this case, at least to me.

Comment: Some wise words I must say! `:)`. The setters don't conform to bean standard and it appears snakeyaml wants that. If I change it back to my old setters (that returns this, instead of void) it errors out. This is going to be part of a test suite and having recently read Effective Java, I thought Builder pattern would be more appropriate. I am ok with beans too. They are easy to create (thanks to eclipse auto code generation `:P`)!